# Upper-bound on sum of two vectors

Tags: vectors, upper-lower-bounds

I have two vectors $a$ and $b$. The resultant of the two vectors is denoted as $c = a+b$. I wish to find the upper bound of $\mid c \mid$ in terms of $\mid a \mid$. Suppose $\phi$ is angle between $a$ and $b$. If $\phi$ is acute and $ \mid a\mid > \frac{\mid b \mid}{2\cos \phi}$, from law of cosines, we have  ${\mid c\mid}^{2} = {\mid a \mid}^2+ {\mid b \mid}^2 - 2 \mid a\mid \mid b \mid  \cos(\phi)$. Using law of cosines we can upper-bound $\mid c\mid$ as  $ {\mid c \mid} < \mid a \mid $. Can we find a similar condition to upper bound $\mid c \mid$, when $\phi$ is obtuse?

Comment: Wait a minute: $|c|<|a|$ is false in general. The only bound you have is the triangle inequality $|c|\le |a|+|b|$. This is sharp, as the inequality becomes an equality if $b=\lambda a$ for some $\lambda \ge 0$.

Comment: The above inequality in false in general,but given the above mentioned conditioned in the Qn, it holds true.

Comment: Ok now I understood. Don't you have a wrong sign in the cosine law?

Comment: the sign is right.

Comment: I maintain that the sign is wrong. Test it with $b=-a$. The angle is $\pi$ and c should vanish, but your formula reads $c^2=(a+b)^2$.

Comment: Sorry for inconsistent notations. I have edited the question. Hope it makes better sense.

Comment: That was not the problem. The problem is that $-2|a||b|\cos \theta$ should be replaced with $2|a||b|\cos \theta$.